# Error using web3.js from OpenZeppelin

Tags: contract-development, truffle, blockchain, truffle-test

Please, i need help. I am using truffle to test a smart contract. I run "truffle develop", then "migrate". The contract has been stored in the network. Then I run the command "test". An error occurred: Cannot find module 'pify'
The tests use web3.js from OpenZeppelin. The file contains the string

const pify = require('pify');

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "web3.js from OpenZeppelin"? (Maybe provide a link or explain how you installed it?)

Comment: Thanks for replying! See link https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/helpers/web3.js

Comment: Did you install with the instructions at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity? If not, what was your installation command, and did you see any errors?

Comment: I copied three files from OpenZeppelin's repository (web3.js, increaseTime.js, latestTime.js) in folder "helpers" . This folder is located next to the contract folder. I call the function "latestTime" in test file. This function depends on web3.js.

Comment: That's not going to work. You need to follow the instructions and actually install the library.

Comment: Did you say about this instructions ( link https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity, the section "Installing OpenZeppelin") ?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the root of your truffle project and run:

```
npm install pify
```

to install the [pify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pify) package.